# .timeout with RxJava observer

Tags: java, android, android-studio, rx-java

I have a subscriber that times out in 10 seconds. Where do I pass what happens once the timeout has occurred?

```
Service.registerUser(registerUserRequest)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .timeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .subscribe(new SingleObserver<RegisterUserResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(RegisterUserResponse registerUserResponse) {


                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    Log.e(LogTags.API, "Error occurred while registering new user.");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            });
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to detect when time out has occured?

Comment: yes that is exactly what I am asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If timeout occurs the onError would be invko `TimeoutException` so you can check that in onError method with this if:

```
if( e instanceof TimeoutException)
```

check this link out : http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/timeout.html

Comment: Ok! Thank you very much. Let me try it out and I will tell you how it worked out.